# How to make Doxygen hide the "class" name in a list of functions?

Tags: doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document the c API of a library. The API is pseudo, as c doesn't have classes, object oriented. My function names are all of the form `className_MethodName(...)`. I use `\class` to create an overview documentation block and `\memberof` in the documentation for each of the "methods" so the functions will be grouped together.

**The rest of this has been heavily edited from the original as my initial observations were not accurate.**

As well as the functions being "class members" they, and those of other classes, are members of a Module created with `\defgroup`. With Doxygen's default configuration settings the function list in the *Modules* section of the ToC and the function list at the top of the containing module's page lists the functions as `className::className_MethodName`. If I set `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES = YES` in my configuration then `className::` disappears from the function list in the module's page but remains in the ToC.

I also have `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES` set in my config.

How can I stop the fully qualified names appearing in the ToC?

It looks to me like a doxygen bug that neither `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES` nor `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES = YES` prevent them appearing.

Comment: Maybe you should create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker to signal the problem, in the issue: please attach a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a, compressed, tar or zip file) that allows to reproduce the problem? Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip albert. I have opened an issue based on the edited description above.